# Map at() throws std::out_of_range for value that exists with seemingly-identical string literal key

Tags: c++, string, dictionary

I have a map using string literals (I think that's what they are?) as keys. The map is called `codingRateMap`. If I try to access it using `codingRateMap.at()` with a string literal, I get what I expect. But, if I try to access with a `std::string` `c_str()` return value, the `at()` call throws `std::out_of_range`. I cannot find any difference between the two string literals. `printf` prints the same thing. `strcmp()` says they're equal. The actual byte values are identical through the null terminator.

Code:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


typedef enum
{
    CODING_RATE_4_5,  // Modem default
    CODING_RATE_4_6
} lora_modem_cfg_coding_rate_t;

static std::map<const char*, lora_modem_cfg_coding_rate_t> CreateCodingRateMap()
{
    std::map<const char*, lora_modem_cfg_coding_rate_t> newMap;
    newMap["CODING_RATE_4_5"] = CODING_RATE_4_5;
    newMap["CODING_RATE_4_6"] = CODING_RATE_4_6;
    return newMap;
}


int main(void)
{
    std::map<const char*, lora_modem_cfg_coding_rate_t> codingRateMap = CreateCodingRateMap();

    const char* coding_rate_selection1 = "CODING_RATE_4_5";

    std::string coding_rate_selection2_string = "CODING_RATE_4_5";
    const char* coding_rate_selection2 = coding_rate_selection2_string.c_str();

    printf("coding_rate_selection1: %s\n", coding_rate_selection1);
    printf("coding_rate_selection2: %s\n", coding_rate_selection2);
    printf("coding_rate_selection1 strlen: %ld\n", strlen(coding_rate_selection1));
    printf("coding_rate_selection2 strlen: %ld\n", strlen(coding_rate_selection2));
    printf("strcmp: %d\n", strcmp(coding_rate_selection1, coding_rate_selection2));

    for (uint8_t idx = 0; idx < 20; idx++)
        printf("%2d %02X %02X\n", idx, coding_rate_selection1[idx], coding_rate_selection2[idx]);
    printf("\n");

    lora_modem_cfg_coding_rate_t codingRate;
    codingRate = codingRateMap.at(coding_rate_selection1);
    printf("%s %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);  fflush(stdout);

    codingRate = codingRateMap.at(coding_rate_selection2);
    printf("%s %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);  fflush(stdout);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
coding_rate_selection1: CODING_RATE_4_5
coding_rate_selection2: CODING_RATE_4_5
coding_rate_selection1 strlen: 15
coding_rate_selection2 strlen: 15
strcmp: 0
 0 43 43
 1 4F 4F
 2 44 44
 3 49 49
 4 4E 4E
 5 47 47
 6 5F 5F
 7 52 52
 8 41 41
 9 54 54
10 45 45
11 5F 5F
12 34 34
13 5F 5F
14 35 35
15 00 00
16 43 0A
17 4F D7
18 44 39
19 49 C4

map_test.cpp 47
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  map::at
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any ideas here? Please forgive the mix of C and C++-isms. I am much more comfortable with the former than the latter. Thank you!

Comment: If you want your map to use strings as keys, use strings (std::string), not pointers.

Comment: A good idea is to compile with AddressSanitinzer: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -g -fsanitize=address,undefined` and then when you run the program, you'll get loads of info.

Comment: Your use of C-isms is the problem; comfort doesn't enter into it. You need to get comfortable with C++; C++ APIs work best when used a cohesive whole, when you use degraded stuff like `const char*` instead of proper C++-string-like things, you create these problems.

Comment: Working on it, slowly. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You told your `map` to use `const char*` as a key, and so it does. It's using the *pointers* as keys. If you give it a different pointer, then it maps that to a different map entry. There's no magic involved, so it doesn't know that you want it to *dereference* the pointer.

The obvious solution is to use a `std::string` or `std::string_view` as a key instead.

Comment: Ah! Duh! Can't believe I didn't realize that. Thank you!

Comment: Not only that, the compiler can be directed to create separate string literals `"x"` if they appear more than once in the codebase.  So you now have `"x"` that can have different addresses, throwing everything off.

Comment: @nabelekt You're not obligated to, but, if you'd like to thank the author of the answer properly, you can do that by  accepting the answer given.

Comment: Just did, thanks. Annoying that I have to wait 10 min after the question/answer is posted to do that.